# Display Overlay on Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, camera

Using this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPhone_Camera_Application_%28Xcode_4%29
I have displayed on the UI an image from the photo library.  I would like to simply overlay some basic text or a shape (like a square) over the UIImage.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Overlay a view on the UIImage. If you want text then add a UILabel after the image then set the frame so it is overlaid in the correct position. For shapes just use the appropriate view for your shape and do the same thing.

Comment: @Joe How would I do this on code though? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I forget that some people can get by only using interface builder. [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW6)

Comment: @Joe Hmmm?  So it's too hard to do?

Comment: This is what I'm using, not sure why it's not working:
`UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,320.0f, 460.0f)];
    UIImage *testimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"test.jpg"];
    UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testimage];
    [subview addSubview:myImageView];`
(image doesn't show up)

Comment: Where do you set the image on `subview`? Also I am not sure if `UIImageView` supports subviews (it may or may not). What you could do is create a normal view then add the 2 images to directly to that view.

Comment: @Joe Hmm, I'm not sure.  That's all the code I've tried so far.  Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an UIImage only or do you display it using an UIImageView?

If you have an UIImageView then you can just add a UILabel as sub view to your image view.

Assuming your UIImageView is named myImageView ...

```
// Create and init the label with any rect. 
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myImageView.frame]; // The lable has the same size as the Image has.
mylabel.text = @"the text";
[myImageView addSubview:myLabel];
//A subview's coordinates are within its superview's coordinates. 
mylabel.center = CGPointMake(myImageView.frame.size.width/2,myImageView.frame.size.height/2) // aligning the centers of the views
//An alternative could be transforming the image's center into the coordinate system of its superviews. That code would look smarter but his example is imho easier to understand.

//Setting front, size, alpha, background colour ... 
...
```

Comment: I've got an image displayed in an imageView, like so: `UIImage *image = [info 
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        
        imageView.image = image;`

Comment: Fine. In that case the code above shoul work. As you see it will center the Lable at the center of the ImageView. Feel free to change that. Just bare in mind that the subviews coordinate system has its origin (0,0) in the top left corner of its superview. Of course you may want to change further attributes like colour, alignment etc.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful reply.  Unfortunately, with your code, the text does appear but the image that it should be appearing on top of disappears, and is replaced so I end up with just black text over a white background.

Comment: Also, do you by chance know how I could do the exact same thing with a simple shape, such as a triangle or circle, instead of text?  Thanks!  (Could I just make a square as a UIImage and then do the same thing somehow?)

Comment: Well, I do not know the default values of UILabel out of the top of my head. But if that is black non-transparent background colour, then that ist exactly what I would expect to happen. :) 

Try mylabel.backgroundcolor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: Well, yes, a separate UIImage with that shape would be the easiest way to implement it. There are smater ways but those are more complex. When adding more subviews then bare in mind that a hierarchy of subviews or a pair of siblings as subview to your original UIImageView may look similar but are not exactly the same. First there is the issue of the coodinate system and second, if you decide to give you shape image some transparence that transparence will be forwarded to all suviews of it. Depending on what you want to achieve, one or the other is better.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks.  Do you think you could please by chance provide me with an example?

Comment: This is what I'm using, not sure why it's not working:
`UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,320.0f, 460.0f)];
    UIImage *testimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"test.jpg"];
    UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testimage];
    [subview addSubview:myImageView];`
(image doesn't show up)

Comment: Works great for my need.  I added the following to remove the label before the label is added.  That way my text field observer can update the text overlay with a fresh label each time the text changes.

`for (UILabel *label in [self.avatarImageView subviews]) {
  [label removeFromSuperview];
}`

Comment: @BarrettClark, it is probalby smarter to re-use the lables that are already there. However, you approach should work.

Comment: @HermannKlecker - good to know.  Thanks for the tip.  I am still getting my bearings around all this Objective-C stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of a UIView, make it transparent, and add an instance of this class, the same size as your image, as a overlay subview on top of the image.  Then, when you want to display something on top of your image, call setNeedsDisplay on the transparent subview, and draw whatever you want (colored rectangles, text, etc.) in the drawRect callback of this view.

To make a UIView subclass transparent, add this to the view class initWithFrame method:

```
[ self setBackgroundColor:[ UIColor clearColor ] ];
```